# Problems with JQuery Mobile multiple pages template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I am stuck with a problem using JQuery mobile and multiple pages: from the #first page I go to the #second, there I have a select with differents options and I have to update the #second page according the selection…so far no problem and it seems it works properly, but there is a rare behavior that I can't avoid any way: if I go forward and backward between the two pages, when I change the selection in the #second page the stuff I have to do is repeated as times as times I went backwards to the #first page.

Try this jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pazjordi/7Ke4Z/) :

1. Go to the #second page
2. Change option: **one** alert pops up
3. Go back to the #first page
4. Go again to the #second page
5. Change again option: **two** alerts pops up !!!
6. And so on…

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
      <link type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
   <body>
       <div data-role="page" id="first" data-theme="b">
           <div data-role="header">
               <h1>Page Title1</h1>
           </div><!-- /header -->

           <div data-role="content">
               <p>Page content goes here.</p>
               <a href="#second">Go to second page</a>
           </div><!-- /content -->

           <div data-role="footer">
               <h4>Page Footer1</h4>
           </div><!-- /footer -->
       </div><!-- /page -->

       <div data-role="page" id="second" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="b">
           <div data-role="header">
               <h1>Page Title2</h1>
           </div><!-- /header -->

           <div data-role="content">
               <p>
                   <select name="listtemp" id="listtemp" data-native-menu="false">
                   <option value ='1'>option 1</option>
                   <option value ='2'>option 2</option>
                   <option value ='3'>option 3</option>
           </select>
               </p>
           </div><!-- /content -->

           <div data-role="footer">
               <h4>Page Footer2</h4>
           </div><!-- /footer -->
       </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
    </html>
   ```

**JS**

```
     $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){   
       $('#listtemp').change(function() {
         alert('change option');
         //Do my stuff here when changing option
         //This code is done as times as times I go back first page…
       });
     });
```

Comment: i dont understand ur prob. can u please tell me your actual problem.

Comment: i can't go back to first page in that fiddle.. am i missing something?

Comment: Use `pagecreate` instead of `pagebeforeshow`. Use the first one to add listeners. Use the second one to manipulate DOM, e.g. show/hide elements, etc.. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7Ke4Z/9/

Answer (score 0):

Of course it would have this behavior since you have added the event inside the pagebeforeshow event. Which means each time the page is shown, the event is set.

You need to keep in mind that all jQuery event functions don't **set** but **add** the event. Hence you can replace `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second'` part with `$(document).ready(`